# sls invoke always gets "Need to provide a name of function to invoke"

Tags: azure-functions, serverless-framework

I have successfully deployed a hello world Azure function named "Hello" using Serverless Framework from my Macbook PRO.

When I use:

```
sls invoke -f Hello -d '{"name":"Azure"}'
```

I always received output:

```
Serverless: Need to provide a name of the function to invoke
```

This is strange since I have provided the correct function name for `-f`.

However, I can invoke the function successfully using CURL.

```
curl -s "https://xxxx-azure.azurewebsites.net/api/Hello?name=azure"
```

What may be the issue?

Comment: Does this command help you: `serverless invoke --function functionName --data '{"name":"Azure"}'`

Comment: @FrankGong Hi, i tried this as well and didn't work either.

Comment: Did you change the `functionName` to `Hello`?

Comment: @FrankGong yes, i did.

Answer (score 0):

If you've verified that you are using the latest version of the Serverless Framework and the Serverless Azure plugin, please open an issue in the [github repository](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions)